# Multiprocess does not apply list change to all processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing

How i can share list changes between multiprocessing parallel process?, im having trouble with that.

```
import multiprocessing

listx = []

def one():
  global listx
  time.sleep(5)
  if 'ok' not in listx:
    print('not in')
  else:
    print('in')

def two():
  global listx
  listx.append('ok')

if __name__ == '__main__':   
  p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=one)
  p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=two)
  p1.start()
  p2.start()

# Output : not in
```

Comment: global data cannot be shared across sub-processes in that way. Take a look at Manager from the multiprocessing module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can used a *managed* list:

```py
import multiprocessing
import time

def one(listx):
    time.sleep(5)
    if 'ok' not in listx:
        print('not in')
    else:
        print('in')

def two(listx):
    listx.append('ok')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with multiprocessing.Manager() as manager:
        listx = manager.list()
        p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=one, args=(listx,))
        p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=two, args=(listx,))
        p1.start()
        p2.start()
        # Wait for processes to complete
        # and results printed before destroying manager process:
        p1.join()
        p2.join()
        print(listx)
```

Prints:

```None
in
['ok']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specifically need multiprocessing, you can use `threading`, as they share resources. Else, you need to use a pipes and queues to synchronize your resources: [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues)

Comment: the code above is an example, I will need to use multiprocessing for my project